# How to determine if a table field was included in an insert trigger

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to check if a certain field was included in an INSERT statement in the context of a trigger that this INSERT statement fired?

For instance, say there's a `customers` table with the following fields: `customerid INT NOT NULL` and `isCrazy BIT(1) DEFAULT b'1'`. This table has a trigger before insert and it is necessary to check if the INSERT statement includes the `isCrazy` field.

```
INSERT INTO customers (customerid) VALUES (1);
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO customers (customerid, isCrazy) VALUES (1, b'0');
```

If the field is defined, then it should proceed to be saved, otherwise there are certain actions to be taken to determine the right value that should be inserted into this field; which would not necessarily be equal to the default.

The problem I'm having is that, if the `isCrazy` field was not included in the INSERT statment, then `NEW.isCrazy` holds the default value (b'1'); same as if the inserted value was actually defined as such. Is it possible to tell the two cases apart?

Comment: `OPTION` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) so if you can, pick another column name or you'll need to escape it each time.

Comment: i not know a result for your problem in a trigger. you can only use a MaxScale proxy. the can do nearly anything. you can parse and rewrite the statement in it. see: https://mariadb.com/de/products/mariadb-maxscale

Comment: @tadman The column is not actually named `option`, I'll edit the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any explicit way to tell if the value was supplied explicitly or came from a default.

The only option I can think of is to use a default value that should never be provided explicitly by the application code. Then you can test if  `NEW.option` is equal to this; if it is, they let it default, and the trigger can replace it with what you really want the default to be.

Comment: Thank you. I did consider this solution, however implementing this change means verifying/testing all other insertions again; so I'm trying to avoid having to do that.